# Copy value from a text field to an input type=hidden when submitting a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

Im working in asp .net mvc3 . I have a form with a textbox and a button. I need to encrypt the value in textbox before i pass it to the controller. So I tried to encrypt the textbox value, store it in a hidden filed and pass the hidden field value to controller. I used the following jquery code inside .submit() , but when i receive the value of hidden filed at controller it is showing default value and not the new value.

```
 $('#myform').submit(function () {
       var hash = "hashed value";
    $("#myhiddenfiled").val(hash);
    alert($('#myhiddenfiled').val());
      return false;
  });
```

Alertbox displays the newly assigned value but the value received at action in controller in old value. Is there any alternative to submit()?

Note::in my case page is submitted by pressing enter button

Comment: Could you show how are you submitting the form to the server? In the code you have shown you are simply returning false from the submit handler meaning that you are canceling the actual submission.

Comment: Im submitting the form by pressing Enter key. Even if submit handler returns false, control is hitting the action to which the form gets submitted.

Comment: That's not possible. You probably have some javascript error. If you return false from the submit handler, then the controller action will not be hit even if you press Enter.

Comment: Generally this kind of task is being achieved using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hash complexity, you could bind a function to the `change` event of the field where the user enters data, set this value on the hash field, then submit the form.

I always like to handle the submit myself, because I can do all kinds of interesting things before submit, then still call submit.

Update: Dimitri had a comment about me misunderstanding the question, so I removed those. Also, Dimitri is right about handling things on submit.

Comment: I'd rather avoid using the `.click()` event for handling form submissions. The user explicitly said that he is submitting the form by pressing the Enter key - the `.click()` event won't be triggered in this case. The `.submit()` event is better for handling form submissions as it covers all cases.

Comment: Eduard, that a workaround for me. If i bind to change event the hashing will be performed on every textchange which is unneccessay. I would prefer perfoming hash just after user press enter button. If there is'nt any option to achieve this, then I will settle with .change() event.

Comment: It would be definitely better to do it only once, before submit. Have you tried to calculate the hash in the submit, just like in your original example, but without the return false at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The change event is a good way to do it

Ex :

```
$('#TEXT_INPUT_ID').on('change',function(e){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.closest('form').find('#hiddenFieldId').val( encrypt($t.val()) );
})
// if any action has to be done on submit except for altering the form input values ... 
.closest('form').on('submit',function(e){
    // flash message
    // ...
})
;
```

Comment: Stev, thanks for the reply. But i had put a note im my question. I do not use a button(rather button press is optional). User may press enter button and submit.

Comment: hoo Sorry ... mistake ! it's not `$('#inputButtonId')` but `$('#TEXT_FIELD_ID')` instead ... gonna edit my post !

Comment: That find over there is a bit strange, if not wrong. You can select the hidden field directly like this: $("#hiddenFieldId")

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your #myhiddenfiled hidden input (rather than the visible input) has name that is the same as the corresponding property of your model.